# Undefined variable: in PHP

Tags: php, variables, pdo, undefined

I'm a fairly new programmer, especially in PHP as i have come from a VB environment.

Below is the function I am having troubles with, as you can see i have had quite a few attempts (in comments). I thought id leave the comments there in case i'm closer with my other attempts.

I have never used PDO before and as you can see this function pretty much allows the user to log in.

The line `if($temp == $_POST['password'])` is where the problem is. Apparently $temp is undefined, but i cannot see why, i have even declared it at the top of the function to be sure. Anyone have any ideas?

```
public function load_user_data() {

        $temp;
        $sql;

        try{

            // $STH = dbHandler::$DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM tblCustomer WHERE email = :email");
            // $STH->bindValue(':email', $this->email); 
            // $STH->execute();
            // $posts = $STH->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); //If only fetch 1 line use just "fetch" instead of "fetchAll"
            // echo '<pre>';
            // print_r($posts);
            // echo '</pre>';

            //--------

            $STH = dbHandler::$DBH->prepare("SELECT password FROM tblCustomer WHERE email = :email");
            $STH->bindValue(':email', $_POST['usermail']); 
            $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

            while($row = $STH->fetch()) {
                $temp = $row;
            }

            //$temp = $STH->fetch(['password']);

            // while($row = $STH->fetch()) {
            //     $temp = $row['password'];
            // }

            //--------

            // $sql = "SELECT password FROM tblCustomer WHERE email = :email";
            // $stmt = $PDO->query($sql); 
            // $row = $stmt->fetchObject();
            // $temp = $row->password;

            if($temp == $_POST['password']) {

                $STH = dbHandler::$DBH->prepare("SELECT * FROM tblCustomer WHERE email = :email");
                $STH->bindValue(':email', $this->email); 
                $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

                echo("we have reached here");

                while($row = $STH->fetch()) {
                    $firstname = $row['firstName'];
                    $lastname = $row['secondName'];
                    $title = $row['title'];
                    $companyname = $row['companyName'];
                    $email = $row['email'];
                    $phone = $row['phone'];
                    $email = $row['mobile'];
                    $startdate = $row['startDate'];
                    $isauthorised = $row['isAuthorised'];
                    $accstop = $row['accStop'];
                    $stopdate = $row['stopdate'];
                }
            }
        }
        catch (PDOException $e) {
            print $e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
        $STH = dbHandler::$DBH->prepare("SELECT password FROM tblCustomer WHERE email = :email");
        $STH->bindValue(':email', $_POST['usermail']); 
        $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        while($row = $STH->fetch()) {
            $temp = $row;
        }
```

First, you need to do:

```
        $STH->execute();
```

before you try to fetch rows.

Second, if the query doesn't match any rows, your `while` loop will never go into the body, so `$temp` will not be set. Since you apparently only expect to get one row from the query, you don't need to use `while`. Instead, do:

```
if ($temp = $STH->execute()) {
    // all the code that depends on finding a row goes here
    ...
}
```

Inside that block, you'll need to do:

```
if ($temp['password'] == $_POST['password'])
```